# VideoView and step play (frame by frame)

Tags: android, android-videoview

I would like to play frame by frame with the videoview.
I have this:

> mVideoView.seekTo(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()+1);

But after this I do not see the frame until I click play... I do not want that, I just want to see the next frame.

Also - can I do the same for previous frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It will not seek while paused. But you can always pause right after seeking, if you use a SurfaceView and a MediaPlayer because VideoView doesn't have the onSeekComplete callback.

```
public void seek() {
mediaplayer.start();
mediaplayer.seekTo(mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()+1);
}

public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {        
mediaplayer.pause();
}
```

This will seek and display something. Unfortunately you will find that this does not allow you to play frame by frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to select the frame you want and next get it as a BitMap using MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(long timeUs). It will work much better than using a MediaPlayer.

I hope it is useful.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: @user1767754 [This](http://android-er.blogspot.kr/2013/05/get-image-frame-in-video-using.html) might help you use MediaMetadataRetriever in order to get frames.